# Alinear mi comentario con el placeholder usando css

Tags: php, html, css, paginación

Quiero cambiar la posicion donde escribo un comentario, no esta alineado con el placeholder, el placeholder esta en la esquina superior izquierda y yo escribo en el centro, pero quiero que se alinee

Este es el input del comentario

```
<input class="coment-input" type="text" name="comentario" placeholder="Escriba su comentario">
```

**Este es su codigo css:**

```
.coment-input{
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 90px;
}

//Y del placeholder

.coment-input::placeholder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

**¿Como le hago para escribir en el comentario(en la esquina superior izquierda donde esta el placeholder)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría utilizar un **textarea** que ya deja el texto alineado en la esquina superior izquierda por defecto, en lugar del **input**.

En principio no es posible alinear verticalmente el texto en un input.

Si es posible alinearlo de forma horizontal mediante la propiedad **text-align**.

En los **input** al setear un **height** automáticamente queda el texto centrado verticalmente.

Una opción para lograr que el texto quede arriba y mantener el tamaño del input podría ser quitar el height y agregar un `padding-bottom: 50px` en este caso.

**Ejemplo de textarea aplicado a tu código:**

```
<textarea name="comentario" class="coment-input" placeholder="Escriba su comentario"></textarea>
```

**Resultado de placeholder:**
[image: Resultado de placeholder]

**Resultados de texto escrito en textarea:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]